# PostgreSQL performance difference with datetime comparison

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to optimize the performance of my PostgreSQL queries. I noticed a big change in the time required to execute my query when I change the datetime in my query by one second. I'm trying to figure out why there's this drastic change in performance with such a small change in the query. I ran an explain(analyze, buffers) and see there's a difference in how they are operating but I don't understand enough to determine what to do about it.  Any help?

Here is the first query

```
SELECT avg(travel_time_all)
FROM tt_data
WHERE date_time >= '2014-01-01 08:00:00' and
      date_time < '2014-01-01 8:14:13' and
      (tmc = '118P04252' or tmc = '118P04253' or tmc = '118P04254' or tmc = '118P04255' or tmc = '118P04256')
group by tmc order by tmc
```

If I increase the later date_time by one second to `2014-01-01 8:14:14` and rerun the query, it drastically increases the execution time.

Here are the results of the explain (analyze, buffers) on the two queries. First query:

```
    GroupAggregate  (cost=6251.99..6252.01 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.829..0.829 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=506
  ->  Sort  (cost=6251.99..6252.00 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.823..0.823 rows=1 loops=1)
    Sort Key: tmc
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
    Buffers: shared hit=506
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tt_data  (cost=36.29..6251.98 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=0.309..0.817 rows=1 loops=1)
          Recheck Cond: ((date_time >= '2014-01-01 08:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date_time < '2014-01-01 08:14:13'::timestamp without time zone))
          Filter: ((tmc = '118P04252'::text) OR (tmc = '118P04253'::text) OR (tmc = '118P04254'::text) OR (tmc = '118P04255'::text) OR (tmc = '118P04256'::text))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 989
          Buffers: shared hit=506
          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tt_data_2_date_time_idx  (cost=0.00..36.29 rows=1572 width=0) (actual time=0.119..0.119 rows=990 loops=1)
            Index Cond: ((date_time >= '2014-01-01 08:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date_time < '2014-01-01 08:14:13'::timestamp without time zone))
            Buffers: shared hit=7
Total runtime: 0.871 ms
```

Below is the second query:

```
GroupAggregate  (cost=6257.31..6257.34 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=52.444..52.444 rows=1 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2693
  ->  Sort  (cost=6257.31..6257.32 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=52.438..52.438 rows=1 loops=1)
    Sort Key: tmc
    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
    Buffers: shared hit=2693
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on tt_data  (cost=6253.28..6257.30 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=52.427..52.431 rows=1 loops=1)
          Recheck Cond: ((date_time >= '2014-01-01 08:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date_time < '2014-01-01 08:14:14'::timestamp without time zone) AND ((tmc = '118P04252'::text) OR (tmc = '118P04253'::text) OR (tmc = '118P04254'::text) OR  (...)
          Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 5
          Buffers: shared hit=2693
          ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=6253.28..6253.28 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=52.410..52.410 rows=0 loops=1)
            Buffers: shared hit=2689
            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tt_data_2_date_time_idx  (cost=0.00..36.31 rows=1574 width=0) (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=990 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((date_time >= '2014-01-01 08:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date_time < '2014-01-01 08:14:14'::timestamp without time zone))
              Buffers: shared hit=7
            ->  BitmapOr  (cost=6216.71..6216.71 rows=271178 width=0) (actual time=52.156..52.156 rows=0 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=2682
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tt_data_2_tmc_idx  (cost=0.00..1243.34 rows=54236 width=0) (actual time=8.439..8.439 rows=125081 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (tmc = '118P04252'::text)
                Buffers: shared hit=483
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tt_data_2_tmc_idx  (cost=0.00..1243.34 rows=54236 width=0) (actual time=10.257..10.257 rows=156115 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (tmc = '118P04253'::text)
                Buffers: shared hit=602
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tt_data_2_tmc_idx  (cost=0.00..1243.34 rows=54236 width=0) (actual time=6.867..6.867 rows=102318 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (tmc = '118P04254'::text)
                Buffers: shared hit=396
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tt_data_2_tmc_idx  (cost=0.00..1243.34 rows=54236 width=0) (actual time=13.371..13.371 rows=160566 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (tmc = '118P04255'::text)
                Buffers: shared hit=619
              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on tt_data_2_tmc_idx  (cost=0.00..1243.34 rows=54236 width=0) (actual time=13.218..13.218 rows=150709 loops=1)
                Index Cond: (tmc = '118P04256'::text)
                Buffers: shared hit=582
Total runtime: 52.507 ms
```

Any advice on how to make the second query as fast as the first? I'd like to increase this time interval by a greater amount but don't want the performance to decrease.

Comment: `group by tmc order by tmc` makes little or no sense, since you are not using this column in the select. Also: stong advice to replace the `(... OR ... OR ...)` list by the corresponding `tmc IN( ... , ... , ...)`

Comment: Either your statistics are off, or your data is very skew. First: rerun vacuum analyze on the table. next: maybe increase statistics_target. Also: you appear to have an index on the timestamp column, but that is not very helpful in filtering the tmc literals.

Comment: I need the group by tmc in order to do the average calculation based on tmc, don't I?  I have python code which is running this query and doing further processing, which is why I also added the order by tmc.  I also have an index on the tmc field in addition to the date field.